# Save API response to server as JSON file with AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm trying to create an app in AngularJS that aggregates data from multiple APIs.  With some public APIs there are request limits and much of the data I want to pull is not updated very frequently, so only one request a month for a particular ID is necessary.  To get past this, I've set up a Factory that first checks for a local file on the server, if it is not present, it then goes to the API and performs a GET request.

From there, once the request is complete, I want to save that file to the server with a name set by a field in the response.

I've found some examples using PHP with AngularJS but I'm not sure on how to save the JSON file with the dynamic name...or if this is even the best thing to do in order to avoid the request limits.

```
var apiUrl = 'https://example.com/api?userID=';

$http.get(apiUrl + $stateParams.userID).
 success(function(data) {
   $scope.content = data;
   $scope.userID = data.userID
    function(){
      $http.post('saveJson.php', $scope.content).then(function() {
      // log success
      });
    };
 }).
 error(function() {
   // log error
 });
```

PHP

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$file = fopen('/var/www/USERID.json','w+');
fwrite($file, $json);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: How big are the responses you get from the 3rd party API?  If the number of characters fall in the low thousands or fewer, you can store the JSON string in your database as opposed to creating a separate file on your server.

Comment: For the most part, yes probably between 500-3000 characters per JSON response.

Is your thought to store the entire JSON response in one column of the database, or mapping each field from the JSON response to a new column?  

My SQL skills are limited and I've looked at something like MongoDB, but I already have a shared hosting service with Site5 right now that I'd like to use in order to keep it cheap.

Comment: With that length, it's better to store the JSON in your database.  It doesn't have to be a traditional column based RDBMS - MongoDB would work also.  You want to avoid storing individual files on your server if possible.  It's a lot more I/O intensive to open a file, read or write to it then to read and write from / to a database.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this in a service, and just call a method from a view button click, it would be more like this:

```
angular.module('app.services', [

])
  .service('MyService', function ($http) {
    var MyService = this;
    this.aggregatedData = { content: [], filename: null };
    this.apiUrl = 'https://example.com/api?userID=';
    this.saveUrl = 'saveJson.php';

    this.getData = function (url) {
      return $http.get(url + $stateParams.userID).then(function (response) {
        MyService.aggregatedData.content.push(response.data);
      });
    };

    this.saveData = function (url, fileName) {
      this.aggregatedData.filename = fileName;
      return $http.post('saveJson.php', this.aggregatedData).then(function () {
        // do something with the post response if desired
      });
    };
  })
```

Then wire up buttons in your view to fetch and save by having the controller call the service methods.